# Rails Rubber EC2 Amazon AWS Railscast

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, amazon-ec2, rubber

Hi I have successfully deployed my app to amazon aws using this railscast

http://railscasts.com/episodes/347-rubber-and-amazon-ec2

my app shows up here on this url http://web01.foo.com/
on my local machine only.

I am slightly confused, if I deployed it why can't other people see it. How do you make it live for all to see?

if anyone is familiar with this rails cast please enlighten me, I am still trying to learn about the architectures of amazon aws hosting.

Thank You
Judy

Answer (score 1):

Rubber automatically sets up your /etc/hosts file for you.  In order to make it publicly viewable you need to have the DNS servers point to that address in your /etc/hosts file.

So basically, go to your DNS host provider, and add an entry that points the domain name you own to the ip address of web01.foo.com and it should load okay.

Comment: Thanks Aditya for you answer.How can I start the sidekiq and solr on AWS.How to use the templates sidekiq and solr in the rubber gem.

Answer (score 1):

In your amazon EC2 dashboard click on the instance. You will get the public domian of your server. Use PUBLIC domain not private one

Comment: Thanks polurupraveen for you answer.How can I start the sidekiq and solr on AWS.How to use the templates sidekiq and solr in the rubber gem.